# Is community wiki not available during beta?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I think several questions are doing to be found that are more appropriate to the wiki concept than a definitive question/answer concept.  Are the options for marking something as wiki not available during beta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community wiki *questions* are a moderator-only feature. Anyone can make a community wiki answer, however.

Keep in mind that you might not really *need* community wiki at all. It shines when answers require collaborative editing, but with suggested edits in place even that is possible without CW.

I don't know which questions you had in mind as CW candidates when you asked this, but check out [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) about community wiki, its uses, and its purpose.

Comment: I would say this question is a typical candidate for community wiki: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36/suitable-citation-management-softaware